# Placing element at bottom of another element

Tags: html, css, svelte

I'm trying to make a button that contains a rectangular progress bar at the bottom of it, but still within it. The bar should be 100% the width of the button. I've tried a bunch of different methods including absolute position, grid, flex, table, and for whatever reason, they either hide the progress bar or display it too high (just below the label). I'm losing my mind trying figure this out. Thanks!

```css
.rect {
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #1d3557;
  background: #faf5ff;
  width: 208px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.rect:hover {
  background:  #f5f6ff;
}
.rect:active {
  background: #eff1ff;
}
.progressBar {
    height: 2px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-right: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(23, 56, 165);
}
.label {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect" on:click>
    <div class="label">I'm a button</div>
    <div class="progressBar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use your browser's devtools inspect facility on your snippet you will see that your 'progress bar' div has no width. Set it to the % width of the amount of progress to see it appear.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with you code on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_html_editor.php, and after I added `width: 100%;` inside the `.progressBar`, I saw a small bar appear at the bottom of the button. Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
  <label for="progress"></label>
  <progress id="progress" value="85" max="100"> 85% </progress>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent {
  width: 10rem;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
}

#progress {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2.5em; /* change this value for position */
}
```

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/sandeep-modi/pen/eYPjeag)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can try.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="rect" on:click>
    <div class="label">I'm a button</div>
    <progress class="progressBar" id="progress" value="75" max="100"> 85% </progress>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rect {
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #1d3557;
  background: #faf5ff;
  width: 208px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.rect:hover {
  background:  #f5f6ff;
}
.rect:active {
  background: #eff1ff;
}
.progressBar {
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(23, 56, 165);
    left:0; right:0; width:100%;
    height:5px;
}
.label {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/tariqmurtuza/pen/MWPBrYJ)